# Generating enemies AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm new to AndEngine and I'm going to make a swimming fish game.
I need to randomly generate jellyfishes and sharks as enemies that needs to be avoided by the fish.

My problem is whenever I run this, there are multiple jellyfishes appearing instead of just one jellyfish that is moving because I want it to be animated.
I saw a code online and applied it to my code, here it goes:

```
// Spawning jellyfish, triggers every 5 seconds
private void createJellyfishSpawnTimeHandler() {
    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
    float mEffectSpawnDelay = 5f;
    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay, true, new ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    addJellyfish();
            }
    });
    getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
}

// Loading jellyfish resources    
private void loadJellyfishResources(){
    this.animatedBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 512, 256,TextureOptions.NEAREST);
    this.jellyfishTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.animatedBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "jellyfish_tiled.png", 4, 1);
    try {
            this.animatedBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 1));
            this.animatedBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
    }
    jellyfishToBeAdded = new LinkedList<Sprite>();
}

// adds a jellyfish at a random location and let it move along the x-axis
private void addJellyfish() {
    // for location
    int x = (int) (camera.getWidth() + jellyfishTextureRegion.getWidth());
    int y = rand.nextInt(high-low) + low;

    jellyfishTarget = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, jellyfishTextureRegion.deepCopy(), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    jellyfishTarget.animate(250);
    scene.attachChild(jellyfishTarget);

    int actualDuration = 15;

    MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(actualDuration, jellyfishTarget.getX(), -jellyfishTarget.getWidth());
            jellyfishTarget.registerEntityModifier(mod.deepCopy());

    jellyfishToBeAdded.add(jellyfishTarget);
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Moving the jellyfish in x axis is OK but you will need to check when it touches the shark or something like this. Of course it's possible to implement but you have Box2D extension which do such things. You will just apply force to the jellyfish (vector) and define the world gravity forces. The engine will do everything for you. You will be also able to define contactListener to detect shark and fish collision. There are many tutorials for it and it's not complicated. If you will have any question feel free to ask me:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you post samples or tutorials for it?

Comment: Yes, this is tutorial I've started with. It shows how to develop simple game from scratch to playable version. It shows great approach of using SceneManager and ResourceManager. It'll also show how you use Box2D extenstion that I mentioned. And a lot more. I can recomend starting AndEnigne adventure with it:) http://www.matim-dev.com/ PS. Don't worry if you won't understand everything at first because it may be confused but when you will start developing your own game using the examples showed in the tutorial you will see how everything became easy:)